# How to handle post edits that result in an error on submittal?

Tags: discussion, error-message

I recently edited a post that contained a large chunk of code. Upon finishing the edit (grammar, spelling, and clarity), I received the following error on submitting the edited post for review:

```
It looks like your post is mostly code; add some more details.
```

I suspect the author had just enough to circumvent this error & I wound up abandoning the edit.

Should details be added in order to properly improve a post and save needed edits in cases like this or is it more appropriate to abandon the edit and comment on the post for the author to clarify/edit themselves?

Comment: can you add a link to the post

Comment: @SagarV, I can't seem to find it, may have been closed/deleted. It was essentially a large block of code and a short description with grammar mistakes & redundancies. After removing redundancies & correcting the grammar/spelling I received the error.